# BIBO stability from impulse response

Tags: real-analysis, integration, control-theory, stability-theory

I've seen two versions of checking BIBO stability from the impulse response $g(t)$.

1. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|g(t)|dt < \infty$
2. $\int_{0}^{+\infty}|g(t)|dt < \infty$

These two integrals can lead to different results because of different integral limits. So I consider these are different conditions. I wonder what is the difference between them and how should I understand them, mathematically and intuitively?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The former condition is the most general one. The latter applies whenever the signal is $g(t)=0$ for $t<0$ that, without loss of generality, is a common assumption in control. Thus, it is a special case of the former and  there is no physical difference between them.

Comment: Maybe also good to mention that the second one uses the assumption of causality.

Comment: Hello Kwin, what do you mean by the assumption of causality? Can I understand it in this way: because I apply the impulse only at time 0, so before time 0, I can assume the impulse response is 0?